# Test java code with JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I have the server functionality of a product packed in jar file, and i have to measure the time of execution of a static method of a class packed in this jar file. Is it possible and if yes, how to do this with JMeter? The only tutorial that i found and that is concerning something similar, is about making junit test and packing it in jar file and putting it in the classpath of jmeter?

Comment: @tak3shi he could call his method with a jsr223 sampler, no?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your jar (with any dependencies if needed) somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar(s) up
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and invoke your method using [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language

That's it, JSR223 Sampler response time will be the value you're looking for. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: And don't forget to tick "Cache compiled script if available" it'll reduce overhead significantly